# Use cookie- and token-based authentication paralelly in one project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a project where MVC and API controllers are used paralelly. Is it possible to use cookie-based auth on MVC controllers and token-based ones in API controllers? How to achieve it?

The problem is - when I construct my Startup.auth this way (below) and use [Authorize] attribute - it doesn't work as expected, because while Web API is called - it checks cookies and allow to execute method without token.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private string PublicClientId { get; set; }
    private OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(DatabaseContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<MobileUserManager>(MobileUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/AuthServices/SignIn"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<MobileUserManager, UserEntity, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                    getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>()))
            }
        });

        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(180),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider()
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override Authorize attribute and check what type of auth is current and what is required like this (just pseudo code):

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private bool IsCookieAuthAllowed { get; }

    public ApolloAuthorizeAttribute(bool isCookieAuthAllowed = false)
    {
        IsCookieAuthAllowed = isCookieAuthAllowed;
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var identity = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal?.Identity;

        if (identity == null)
            return false;

        if (identity.IsCookie())
            return IsCookieAuthAllowed && identity.IsAuthenticated;

        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```